# What does [1] => 0 mean in this array?

Tags: php, arrays

I know this must be a fairly simple question, but I haven't managed to stumble across an answer yet.

I have the following array

```
$qid[0][0]=1;
$qid[1][0]=2;
$qid[2][0]=3;
$qid[3][0]=4;
```

When I use print_r($qid) I get the following

```
Array ( 
 [0] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 0 ) 
 [1] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) 
 [2] => Array ( [0] => 3 ) 
 [3] => Array ( [0] => 4 )
)
```

I don't understand  **[1] => 0**

in

`[0] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 0 )`

If someone could explain what  **[1] => 0** means in this array, I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks.

**EDIT:** It turns out that my array was indeed different to what I had written above, because it had been modified later in the code. Thanks everyone for the great answers. I'm still reading over them all and trying to make my mind understand them (Arrays turn my mind to jello).

Comment: You probably find `var_dump()` more insightful than `print_r()`.

Comment: it is a two dimensional array so ( [0] => 1 [1] => 0 ) is referring to the second element of the first position in the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[1] => 0` denotes an array element with the value `0`.

The numbers in `[]` are array keys.  So `[1]` is the second element of a numerically indexed array, (which starts with `[0]`), and the value of the second element (`[1]`) is `0`.

PHP uses `=>` as an operator to relate array keys/indices to their values.

#### So an overall explanation of this structure:

```
Array ( 
 [0] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 0 ) 
 [1] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) 
 [2] => Array ( [0] => 3 ) 
 [3] => Array ( [0] => 4 )
)
```

The outer array is a numerically indexed array, and each of its elements is a sub-array.  The first of them (`[0]`) is an array containing 2 elements, while the rest of them (`[1] through [3]`) are arrays containing only one single element.

Comment: That's `print_r` output, not a comma missing but a/some newline(s).

Comment: I think print_r doesn't output commas.

Answer (score 3):

That two-dimensional array is actually a one-dimensional array of arrays, which is why you're getting the nesting. The `[x] => y` bit simply means that index `x` of the array has the value `y`.

Now your output in this case doesn't actually match your code, since

```
$qid[0][0]=1;
$qid[1][0]=2;
$qid[2][0]=3;
$qid[3][0]=4;
print_r($qid);
```

produces:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ( [0] => 1 )
    [1] => Array ( [0] => 2 )
    [2] => Array ( [0] => 3 )
    [3] => Array ( [0] => 4 )
)
```

If you wanted to get:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 0 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [0] => 3 ) 
    [3] => Array ( [0] => 4 )
)
```

(with the first array having two elements), you'd actually need:

```
$qid[0][0]=1;
$qid[0][1]=0;

$qid[1][0]=2;

$qid[2][0]=3;

$qid[3][0]=4;

print_r($qid);
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably added a second item to $qid[0] somewhere ($qid[0][1] = 0). This code

```
$qid[0][0]=1;
$qid[1][0]=2;
$qid[2][0]=3;
$qid[3][0]=4;
```

outputs the the correct values for me (without [1] => 0:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 3 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 4 ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

It means that your index 0 in the original Array contains another Array of 2 items.
Specifically `[1] => 0` means that the 2nd item of the "child" Array contains the number 0.

Answer (score 1):

```
[1] => 0
```

in this simple way we can say that 1 is your array key and 0 is value for the 1 key
0 is store at the 1 key of the array

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, you have a numerically indexed multidimensional array. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php should have all the information you need to read up on this.

As to *why* you have the `[1] => 0`, you'll need to look a little deeper into your code to see where it gets assigned.

Answer (score 1):

I got the following result after printing out the array using print_r:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
    )

    [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3
    )

    [3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 4
    )

)
```

I guess, you might have set a value for $gid[0][1] somewhere in your code.